# Find all urls in file

Tags: python

Okay, my problem is that my code only finds and prints the last url in the list, not all of the urls as i want.

```
def convert(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst)

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        test = convert(lines)
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', lines)

print(urls)
```

this is a part of the txt file:

```
28                               https://letterboxd.com/film/deep-blue-sea/
29                   https://letterboxd.com/film/the-chronicles-of-riddick/
30                          https://letterboxd.com/film/sonic-the-hedgehog/
31                         https://letterboxd.com/film/the-babysitter-2017/
```

So i don't know what is the problem with my code, i dont understand why it doesnt loop through all the lines in the file, it only prints out the last url in the list, https://letterboxd.com/film/the-babysitter-2017/, instead of all the urls in the list.

Comment: Don't you want to run your regex on test instead of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lines` is each line in the file. You want to do something like the following:

```
def convert(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst)

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    test = convert(lines)
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', lines)

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no need to first read all the lines then `join` them. Instead you can directly read all the data in the file using `f.read()` in one step.

**Try this:**

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', f.read())
```

Now executing `print(urls)` will produced the desired output.